# How to clean lines in image and make sure image is not distorted using python language in opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, canny-operator

How can I clean the image from the lines on it and ensure that the image is not distorted?

1st Picture:
[image: 1st picture]

2nd Picture:
[image: 2nd picture]

Answer (score 0):

There is no single solution for this purpose and noise removal, but you can use the following two parameters, although it is difficult to completely remove due to the color of the lines and the image.

```
# apply morphology close and open to make mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10,10))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
```

and then:

```
# do OTSU threshold 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
otsu = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

[image: this]